# How to place the deadlines in “Earliest deadline first scheduling” in this question?

Tags: scheduling, process-scheduling

So I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mk2ldyjKtBc) to get the concept of "Earliest deadline first scheduling". I have to implement this task >>> [TASK](https://ibb.co/Lxbrm3P). Now the thing which I am not getting in this Task is that what does "Start of next period" means in the deadline column. Still, I have implemented it >>> [Here](https://ibb.co/m9cKJqC). I placed the deadlines with a RED downward arrow while the blue upward arrows meant the periods of the respected processes. But again I am not sure whether my approach was correct in understanding the "Start of next period" because it could also mean the start of every period. Once I am sure that I have placed the deadlines correctly, then I will solve the question.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. Please add enough information to answer your question helpfully to its body, see [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As neither period is a multiple of the other, *start offset* is immaterial. If an exclusive resource needs to be scheduled *non-preemptively* (please add in the question - I'm not going to wait for such in a video), trouble starts when the sum of resource demands exceeds availability (Here: P1 .5, P2 .46 - close enough to 1 to get "interesting"). And when the gap in the schedule of any task is smaller than the longest task. (Anything else trivial?)

Comment: @greybeard I am not getting what you want to convey. I am just asking whether I have placed the deadlines correctly according to the question?

Comment: Do you have a specific question?  We are a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a specific question.  "I am not sure whether my approach was correct" is not focused enough to be a good fit here.  We discourage "please check whether my solution is correct" questions as they are unlikely to be of use to anyone else in the future.

Comment: I cannot explain my problem more than that. I have even put the tutorial link of "Earliest deadline first scheduling" which is a very important topic operating system subject. I have provided the screenshot of a question. There is a trick part in the question i.e in the deadline column , there are no exact deadlines being mentioned e.g 2,4,6,any number so that it is easier to built the chart. But they have mentioned "Start of next period". I provided a solution that I think might be true. I don't think I can explain the scenario more than that.